# IMAP: Return several headers in one command

Tags: email, imap

I am new to IMAP commands, but I know that in IMAP you can use this command to get header of a message:

```
fetch Message_Id (RFC822.HEADER)
```

or

```
fetch Message_Id:* (body[header.fields (from to subject date)])
```

where Message_Id is the message id like: 1, 2, 3 ...

so i need a command that gets the headers of all messages in a selected folder with only one command, that I receive a list of headers, something like this:

```
fetch * (RFC822.HEADER)
```

or

```
fetch *:* (body[header.fields (from to subject date)])
```

is that possible? is there such a command?

Comment: Certainly. What've you tried? One of your suggestions will work...

Comment: I tried them all, but i didn't start from the first message like 1:* to get the whole list as Max explaind, so that was the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` is for a range.  So `1:3` means messages from 1 to 3.

`*` does not mean "every message", it means "the last message", whatever that may be.

So, the range you want is simply `1:*`, from message 1 until the last message.

Comment: thanks, that did work, however when I used: fetch 1 (RFC822.HEADER) the message remains as Unseen (if it was unseen) but now when i use: fetch 1:* (UID FLAGS body[header.fields (from to subject date)])  it gives me all headers in the folder, and thats nice, but all of the messages become seen (as if the seen flag were added) , is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Fetching BODY[anything] sets the \Seen flag by default.  Use the BODY.PEEK[...] variant, instead, which does not.  This is all in RFC3501.

Comment: fetch 1:* (UID FLAGS body.peek[header.fields (from to subject date)])